# display button after viedo watched

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am trying to display a video for my website members but I need to
show a button to submit the form to me confirming that they watched the video fully without any skip
I have difficulty setting the timer to show the button based on the video length not setting a custom time.
I need to set the time based on the video length and stop the timer if the user pauses the video.

here is my code

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <video controls id="myVideo" class="embed-responsive-item" src="/assets/MSFS.mp4" allowfullscreen></video></div>
```

JS

```
   <script>
 

      $(document).ready(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#proceed").show();
      }, 5000);
    });
    </script>
```

button

```
<button id="proceed" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Submit</button>
```

basically what is happening the button is displayed after 5 seconds I need to change 5 seconds to the length of the video. Is there any way to get the length of the video and set it instead of manually entering it? How to stop the timer if the video pauses?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry out of answers for 30 mins, but videos and audio have an 'onended' property according to w3schools: `var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.onended = function() {
    alert("The video has ended");
};`  So you could use that to set the proceed button to enabled or visible for example. Disable seeking/skipping with something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/o13zcrxf/4/